# Can't connect to router

Tags: router, fritzbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reset a Fritz!Box DSL router to factory settings?](https://superuser.com/questions/350980/how-to-reset-a-fritzbox-dsl-router-to-factory-settings)

I need to change the setting of router Fritz Box. The setting were set by another person. I can't connect to router using cable, may be standard port or address were changed. So the only option is to switch to factory settings. Usually there is a button which deletes all the settings. I read the documentation and they tell to call the number #991*15901590* on the router. Do I have to connect telephone to router?

Comment: What model is it that you have?

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the router via Ethernet or WiFi and negotiate an IP address via DHCP (most Operating System configurations will do that automatically). The Fritz!Box should now be set as the default gateway. You can use `route` on the command line to determine it.

If DHCP doesn't work anymore, you can still scan the whole private IPv4 address range. For example, `nmap -sP 192.168.0.0/16 10.0.0.0/8 172.16.0.0/20` will list a Fritz!Box without a configured DHCP server (but functioning IPv4).

Comment: DCHP seems to be not working. And how can I connect if I don't know the subnet?

Comment: @damluar If DHCP isn't working, it's seriously messed up. How did you find out that that's the case? If you watch the incoming packets with wireshark, do *any* Ethernet packets come in?

Comment: I just looked at wireshark. No DHCP Offer comes in response to DHCP Discover

Answer (score 1):

No matter how the FritzBox is configured, it is always reachable via ethernet cable http://192.168.178.254 - there you'll find an option to reset to factory settings.

Comment: In documentation it's written that it's available from 192.168.178.1. But it's not in my case.

Comment: 192.168.178.1 is the standard address (factory setting or after a reset). 192.168.178.254 is always available, too. To reach that address, your interface on the desktop must be in the same subnet 192.168.178.0, and it works only via ethernet cable.

Comment: Not available. Checked 1 hour ago

Comment: What model is that FritzBox. You could also connect a phone to the RJ-11 connector, then dial that #991*15901590*.