# How to reset a Fritz!Box DSL router to factory settings?

Tags: router, reset, fritzbox

I need to change the setting of router Fritz Box. The setting were set by another person. I can't connect to router using cable, may be standard port or address were changed. So the only option is to switch to factory settings. Usually there is a button which deletes all the settings. I read the documentation and they tell to call the number #991*15901590* on the router. Do I have to connect telephone to router?

Comment: What's the exact model number of the Fritz Box?  It'll be something like WLAN 7390 or WLAN 7270.

Comment: It's difficult to say, cause it's not written on the router. It's just "Fritz!Box von WLAN". But it looks like 7113: http://www.avm.de/de/Produkte/FRITZBox/FRITZ_Box_Fon_WLAN/index.php

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the same problem, but no analogue telephone at hand. So i tried it with wireshark to find my "lost" fritz.box (i chose: "get IP from DHCP") without success.

After some reading i found a solution:
The fritz.box 7170 is always available on http://169.254.1.1. (Just set the IP address manually in the range of 169.254.1.x)

Comment: Works for Fritz!Box 7360v2 as well.

Comment: And for the 7530

Answer (score 10):

1. Set your IP manually to something in the 169.254.1.x range
   (169.254.1.3)
2. Unplug the router and wait 10 seconds Plug it back in
3. Open a command windows (cmd) and do ping 169.254.1.1 -t
4. As soon as you get reply's go to the webinterface at 169.254.1.1
5. You have a option 'click here if you forgot your password' (click on here)
6. Then click 'Restore factory settings' (This option disappears after about 10 minutes)

Answer (score 4):

I'm reading through [the manual](http://fritzbox.com.au/manual/Manual_FRITZBox_Fon_WLAN_7270.pdf) now of this (bizarre) WLAN/router/ADSL modem combo appliance.  Yes, it does appear that you need to find an analog touch-tone phone and plug it into the RJ11 (telephone) port on the device and dial those keys to reset it to factory default if you do not have the password (the manual states that it cannot be recovered without factory reset).

Hopefully you have your PPPoE/ADSL authentication information from your ISP, otherwise you'll have to call them to have it reset.

Comment: That's just incredible.

Comment: I know. #mindblown

Comment: Boo for no pulse dial support, though!  Discrimination against rotary phones!

Comment: If the thought of hunting around for a telephone isn't persuasive enough to look for a new router, you might like to know that Fritz!box is in a GPL dispute at the moment (according to wikipedia), which could go badly for the company and they may end-of-life your product.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Connect the analogue telephone to the router and dial the number. You should hear a long beep in the handset and it should revert to factory settings.

If this doesn't work, try firmware recovery and/or update.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to connect an (analog) telephone to the box.

Or connect via cable, set your PC to get an IP via DHCP and then browse to `http://fritz.box`. After that follow the instructions for a password reset, which also does a factory reset.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But I can't connect to it. I tried DCHP, tried manual setting of my IP like 192.168.178.10. No way...

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to use **port 456** for the https connection, for example:

```
https://169.254.1.1:456/
```

Fritz often does not use standard port. The plaintext server on my FRITZ!Box WLAN 7390 http://169.254.1.1/ You might also want to try LAN ports 2, 3, 4 with reference to LAN port 1. One of the other might have special significance, I think LAN 1 can be on a different VLAN if it wants to be perhaps. Use the wired Ethernet not Wireless when setting up for the first time!

Answer (score 0):

same here. i have no analog phone, and factory reset via webinterface does not work

in theory, it should work to connect my soundcard output to the [TAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TAE_connector) phone socket of the fritzbox, and send the dial tones

to generate the [DTMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling) dial tones, install [dtmf-dial](https://github.com/TJNII/dtmfdial) and run

```
dial "#991*15901590*" | aplay -
```

or

```
dial --tone-time 200 --silent-time 200 "#991*15901590*" |
  ffmpeg -f u8 -ar 8000 -i - -f lavfi -t 1 \
  -i anullsrc=channel_layout=mono:sample_rate=8000 \
  -filter_complex "[1:a][0:a][1:a]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1" \
  -y fritzbox-reset-dial.flac
```

i just need a way to connect my soundcard to the TAE phone socket, without breaking something...

status: i just noticed that my fritzbox has no TAE phone socket. so currently, im trying to push new [firmware](https://github.com/Freetz-NG/freetz-ng) to my fritzbox

possible solutions:

- use recover.exe from [download.avm.de/fritzbox/](https://download.avm.de/fritzbox/). this will tell you to power-cycle the fritzbox, and then it will try to connect to 192.168.178.1 or so. this is the same procedure used by openWRT or freetz to flash firmware. see also [FRITZ!OS der FRITZ!Box wiederherstellen](https://avm.de/service/fritzos-der-fritzbox-wiederherstellen/)
- use an old analog telephone to generate DTMF dial tones

  - go to the next trash dump, and in the electronics waste, look for an old wired analog telephone with a TAE connector, or a RJ11 connector
  - buy an old analog phone for about 5 euros on ebay
  - must be a "wired" phone, no wireless DECT phone
  - ask a neighbor if i can use his analog phone
- use an old USB 56k dial-up modem to generate DTMF dial tones

  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624526/create-a-dialtone-from-56k-modem
  - buy an old USB 56k modem about 5 euros on ebay
- use a raspberry pi zero to generate DTMF dial tones

  - [Send DTMF Tones with Raspberry Pi](https://iotbytes.wordpress.com/send-dtmf-tones-with-raspberry-pi/) - dial a phone number and pass the DTMF digits using Raspberry Pi, USRobotics USR5637 USB Dial-up Modem, and Python script
  - [How do I connect my raspberry pi to a landline phone to process calls?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/58774/how-do-i-connect-my-raspberry-pi-to-a-landline-phone-to-process-calls)
  - [piphons](https://github.com/epsilonrt/piphons): Phone line interface with DTMF decoder and speech synthesis for Pi board
  - [Connecting the pi to a phone using a RJ11 cable to send and receive audio](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/122027/connecting-the-pi-to-a-phone-using-a-rj11-cable-to-send-and-receive-audio)
- connect my soundcard to the phone line of my fritzbox

  - transformer isolation circuit: most circuits are based on a 600:600 ohm isolation transformer (EI14 600 Ohm)
  - [Phone to audio interface](http://www.repairfaq.org/ELE/F_ASCII_Schem_Tel.html#ASCIISCHEMTEL_004)
  - [Audio interfaces to telephone lines](https://www.epanorama.net/documents/telecom/teleinterface.html#audioint)

    - capacitor isolation circuit: In some special case the audio interface is built without isolation transformers. In those cases the audio signal is passed from telephone line through the capacitor which blocks the DC from telephone line. This type of isolation works quite well in applications where you don't want to use the transformer but you still want to get some audio from the line. Typical application is called ID boxes.
    - hookswitch: When your telephone is in on-hook state the "TIP" is at about 0v, while "RING" is about -48v with respect to earth ground. When you go off hook, and current is drawn, TIP goes negative and RING goes positive (I mean less negative). A typical off hook condition is TIP at about -20v and ring at about -28v. This means that there is about 8V voltage between the wires going to telephone in normal operation condition. The DC-resistance of typical telephone equipment is in 200-300 ohm range and current flowing through the telephone is in 20-50 mA range.
- [How to dial a phone number via DTMF tones?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/506736/how-to-dial-a-phone-number-via-dtmf-tones)

  - you need to take a DC current from the line to signal to the telephone exchange equipment (SLIC or subscriber line interface card) that you are "off-hook". Putting a resistor across the line to draw circa 25 mA would correctly signal to the SLIC that you are off-hook. Probably about 1 kohm would do the job.
  - TODO what is the "line voltage" of the fritzbox TAE socket? probably 12 Volt, because the fritzbox runs with 12V
  - [Line card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_card): A line card or digital line card is a modular electronic circuit designed to interface with a telecommunications access network.
- [Land line circuit suggestion / DTMF project](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/98655/land-line-circuit-suggestion-dtmf-project)
- DTMF in german: Mehrfrequenzwahlverfahren = MFV, kurz: Tonwahl

[A typical capacitor isolation circuit](https://www.epanorama.net/circuits/teleinterface.html#noisolation)

```
               C1  R1
 Line ---------||-/\/\--o------O
                        |
                        \
                     R3 /       Audio out
                        \
               C2  R2   |
 Line ---------||-/\/\--o------O
```

R3 can be omitted, so you just need C1 R1 and C2 R2